# Handling remoteviews in android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android widget and currently i am developing widget where i am using more images, it runs perfectly but sometimes it throws error `Failed Binder Transaction`, 
I know the problem is with remoteviews, can anyone tell me how to handle remoteviews in android widget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because all the changes to the RemoteViews are serialised (e.g. setInt and setImageViewBitmap ). The bitmaps are also serialised into an internal bundle. Unfortunately this bundle has a very small size limit.

Make sure you downsize the bit map. Refer the following code.

```
 public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

 final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

 int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
 int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

 photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

 return photo;
 }
```

This newHeight should be small (~100 for every square it should take on the screen) and use it for your widget, and your problem will be solved :)